# Separation and Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

I am just learning the definitions of a topological space being separated, but what is the relationship between separated topological space and a Hausdorff space?

The definition of separated is that Y = $A \bigcup B$  such that A , B do not intersect, but this seems very similar to the definition of Hausdorff space.

thank you very much

Comment: What properties for $A$ and $B$!

Comment: By separated, do you mean [disconnected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Formal_definition)?

Comment: yes the definition of separated according to Munkres, is that U, V are subsets nonempty of X such that their union is equal to X and they do not intersect.  the text does not give the definition of disconnected spaces.

Comment: I doubt Munkres wrote word-for-word what you report.

Comment: Pg 148 , A separation of X is a pair U,V of disjoint nonempty open subset of X whose union is X.  - Munkres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the difference:

- $\Bbb R $ with the usual topology is Hausdorff, but not separated.
- $]-\infty, -1 [\cup ]1, + \infty [$ with the usual topology induced from $\Bbb R$ is Hausdorff *and* separated.

Comment: I don't understand how the standard topology of R is not separated?  considering (-1,0) $\bigcup (0,1)$ is a basis for a subset of R, this is separated.  and  I Think this is hausdorf as well.  we can extend this idea to the entire real line, but this is wrong somehow.

Comment: The Hausdorff property is related to *points* of the space, not subsets of it. Being Hausdorff and separated are distinct concepts. Remember: a topological space $(X, \tau)$ is Hausdorff if given any $x,y \in X$, we have $V_x, V_y \in \tau $ such that $x \in V_x$ and $y\in V_y$, with $V_x \cap V_y = \varnothing $.

Comment: yes you are correct thank you.  But Can you give a little insight to how the standard topology on R is not separated? I think that $(-1,0) \bigcup (0,1)$ $\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are contained in the standard topology and are separated (?).  any advice will be greatly appreciated.  thank you again.

Comment: Can you write $\Bbb R = A \dot{\cup} B$, with $A,B$ open sets?

Comment: I see. you can not.  in my example the union excludes 0, which is in R.  thus we can not generate R from disjoint unions of open intervals.  (I think this is the correct logic) ?

Comment: $\Bbb R$ can't be written as a union of open disjoint sets. Also, your union above left out $]-\infty, -1]$ and $[1, +\infty [$, besides $\{0\}$.

Comment: I do not really understand the above notation?

Comment: What notation? ${}{}{}$

Comment: ] $- \infty, -1] $ and [1, $+\infty[$ is this the same as $(\infty, -1]$ and $[1, + \infty)$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.